# Optimize my long mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
    n.id,
    n.title,
    n.text,
    n.date,
    IFNULL(ap.name, a.name) AS name,
    IFNULL(ap.path, a.path) AS path,
    IFNULL(ap.extension, a.extension) AS extension,
    IFNULL(ap.width, a.width) AS width,
    IFNULL(ap.height, a.height) AS height,
    IFNULL(ap.server, a.server) AS server,
    s.id AS source_id,
    s.name AS source_name
FROM news n
LEFT JOIN news_attachments na ON n.id = na.news_id AND na.cover = 1
LEFT JOIN attachments a ON na.attachments_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN attachments ap ON a.id = ap.parent AND ap.width = 136
JOIN sources s ON n.sources_id = s.id
WHERE n.moderate = 1 AND n.delete = 0
GROUP BY n.id
ORDER BY n.date DESC
LIMIT 25
```

I have this SQL query. And I have a question is it good or not? Maybe I can improve it?

In this part

```
LEFT JOIN attachments a ON na.attachments_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN attachments ap ON a.id = ap.parent AND ap.width = 136
```

I load a preview of image, then in select:

```
    IFNULL(ap.name, a.name) AS name,
    IFNULL(ap.path, a.path) AS path,
    IFNULL(ap.extension, a.extension) AS extension,
    IFNULL(ap.width, a.width) AS width,
    IFNULL(ap.height, a.height) AS height,
    IFNULL(ap.server, a.server) AS server
```

This mean if it have a preview of image, then use it otherwise use original image

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                             | key                  | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | ALL    | PRIMARY,id                                | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                     |    4 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | n     | ref    | fk_news_sources1_idx                      | fk_news_sources1_idx | 4       | base.s.id              |   93 | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | na    | ref    | PRIMARY,fk_news_has_attachments_news1_idx | PRIMARY              | 4       | base.n.id              |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,id                                | PRIMARY              | 4       | base.na.attachments_id |    1 |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ap    | ALL    | NULL                                      | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL                     | 3720 |                                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------+----------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: what does explain say ?

Comment: I'm not too good at optimization but I'd try sticking a compound index (parent, width) on the attachments table.

Comment: So is this query *slow* (and what's slow for you) or just *long* ?

Comment: It's long and maybe it need any optimization. Thanks about index width and parent, I forgot about it.

Comment: Do you have an index on `news.date`?

Comment: No i haven't date index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all `news` records have `sources`, try adding an index to news on `moderate`, `delete` and `date` (in that order) and then try the following query:

```
SELECT
    n.id,
    n.title,
    n.text,
    n.date,
    IFNULL(ap.name, a.name) AS name,
    IFNULL(ap.path, a.path) AS path,
    IFNULL(ap.extension, a.extension) AS extension,
    IFNULL(ap.width, a.width) AS width,
    IFNULL(ap.height, a.height) AS height,
    IFNULL(ap.server, a.server) AS server,
    s.id AS source_id,
    s.name AS source_name
FROM (select *
      from news
      WHERE moderate = 1 AND delete = 0
      ORDER BY date DESC
      LIMIT 25) n
LEFT JOIN news_attachments na ON n.id = na.news_id AND na.cover = 1
LEFT JOIN attachments a ON na.attachments_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN attachments ap ON a.id = ap.parent AND ap.width = 136
JOIN sources s ON n.sources_id = s.id
GROUP BY n.id
```

Comment: I have also added ORDER BY n.date DESC in the end, because it show results head over heels

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the attachments table has a key on parent (or possibly better a key covering bother parent and width). Suspect this is the major issue.

I suspect that the moderate and delete columns on the news table won't narrow things down enough to make an index on them useful.

I also presume that there are many more source records than there are news records, hence MySQL has chosen to take sources and join news to that rather than the other way round.

Comment: No, sources about 4 now and will be max 20-30. But thank you for your answer, it is very useful.

Comment: Ooops, sorry got it the wrong way round. Meant that there will be many more news stories than sources, hence why it has taken sources and joined news onto that.